# Presto/SQL - Converting string timestamp to date throws error

Tags: sql, date, datetime, select, presto

NOTE: I am running my query in **Qubole's** presto and sql command engine.

I am trying to convert my string timestamp to just date but none of the options are working out.

My string timestamp looks like `2017-03-29 10:32:28.0`
and I want to have it like `2017-03-29`

I have tried following queries to convert this *string* timestamp to retrieve date

```
1. select cast(created as date) from table1
```

> Value cannot be cast to date: 2017-05-26 17:23:58.0

```
2. select cast(from_iso8601_timestamp(created) as date) from table1
```

> Invalid format: "2014-12-19 06:06:36.0" is malformed at " 06:06:36.0"

```
3. select date(created) from table1
```

> Value cannot be cast to date: 2012-10-24 13:50:00.0

How I can convert this timestamp to date in presto/sql?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as explained in [the documentation](https://prestodb.github.io/docs/current/language/types.html#date-and-time), prestoDB seems to expect timestamps in a format `'2001-08-22 03:04:05.321'`, and dates in a `'2001-08-22'`.

One solution would be to use [a string function](https://prestodb.github.io/docs/current/functions/string.html) to extract the relevant part of the string before converting it. We know that the date part is located before the first space in the string, so.

If you need the date part as a *string datatype*:

```
split_part(created, ' ', 1)
```

If you need the date part as a *date datatype*:

```
cast(split_part(created, ' ', 1) as date)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try to use one of the following solutions:

```
  SELECT 
  '2017-03-29 10:32:28.0' AS input_string,
  DATE(date_parse('2017-03-29 10:32:28.0', '%Y-%m%-%d %H:%i:%s.%f')) AS solution_1,
  DATE(try_cast('2017-03-29 10:32:28.0' as timestamp)) AS solution_2
```

Comment: try_cast worked for me, thanks!!